# I am trying to use texblob translator to translate a .csv file into english but I am getting the following error

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, translate, textblob

Here is the code that is causing problems

```
import pandas as pd
from textblob import TextBlob
df = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/prana/Downloads/Sample tweet.csv') # path to csv file
df['english'] = df['tweet'].str.encode('ascii', 'ignore').apply(lambda x:TextBlob(x.strip()).translate(to='en'))
df.to_csv("C:/Users/prana/Downloads/test.csv") # your documents folder
```

and the error I get is

```
TypeError: cannot use a string pattern on a bytes-like object'
```

Does anyone have any idea of how to go forward?

Comment: Could you show a couple of rows from the data file "Sample tweet.csv" so we can see what the problem is?  Also https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask shows how to ask a good question.

Comment: Is the ['Tweet'] column definitely type str? Do you need to convert it with df['Tweet'].astype(str).str.encode...etc.?

Comment: @PaulBrennan "#Elecciones2020 | En #Florida: #JoeBiden dice que #DonaldTrump solo se preocupa por Ã©l mismo. El demÃ³crata fue anfitriÃ³n de encuentros de electores en #PembrokePines y #Miramar. Clic AQUÃ â¬‡ï¸â¬‡ï¸â¬‡ï¸
â €
ðŸŒ
#ElSolLatino #yobrilloconelsol
Usa 2020, Trump contro Facebook e Twitter: coprono BidenÂ   #donaldtrump 
"#Trump: As a student I used to hear for years, for ten years, I heard China! In 2019! And we have 1.5 and they don't

Comment: @Linden i want to convert it into a string but all of the data is not string. The ultimate goal is to just translate the text into english,